# CMake ExternalProject_Add use automatically set variables

Tags: cmake, coin-or-clp

According to [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html), `ExternalProject_Add` sets unset directory variables itself.

> If any of the above ..._DIR options are not specified, their defaults are computed as follows. If the PREFIX option is given or the EP_PREFIX directory property is set, then an external project is built and installed under the specified prefix:
>
> ```
> TMP_DIR      = <prefix>/tmp
> STAMP_DIR    = <prefix>/src/<name>-stamp
> DOWNLOAD_DIR = <prefix>/src
> SOURCE_DIR   = <prefix>/src/<name>
> BINARY_DIR   = <prefix>/src/<name>-build
> INSTALL_DIR  = <prefix>
> ```

In the following example I want to add COIN-OR-CLP as an external project with a custom `CONFIGURE_COMMAND` because CLP uses Autotools. This works.

```
include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(${EXT_PROJ}
                    PREFIX ${EXT_PROJ}
                    SVN_REPOSITORY https://projects.coin-or.org/svn/Clp/stable/1.16/
                    UPDATE_COMMAND svn cleanup  # Beause otherwise svn will fail on consecutive runs
                    CONFIGURE_COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${EXT_PROJ}/${EXT_PROJ}/src/${EXT_PROJ}/configure
```

)

However I think it'd be cleaner to use the generated paths instead manually passing it.

Is there a way to use `${SOUCRE_DIR}` in `ExternalProject_Add` without setting it explicitly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All directories you refer to can be used in `ExternalProject_Add` COMMAND's with `<...>` notation:

```
CONFIGURE_COMMAND <SOURCE_DIR>/configure
```

For some reason, this feature is described at the end of `ExternalProject_Add_Step` function's description, not in the function `ExternalProject_Add`.